# Powermail 4.4.0 - performance issues while editing records in backend

Tags: performance, typo3, powermail

i have a specific problem regarding editing mail records in TYPO3 backend.
When you select a mail record via **List module > 'folder' > Mails 'record'** it takes a very long time for the contents to show.

I figured that it has something to do with the high number of the stored records (>12.000 mail records & >140.000 answer records).

Is there a way to create a more performant query ?
My thought of a solution was to maybe override certain field TCAs, but until now i wasn't able to adjust the query to fit my needs.

Thanks and regards.

System:
TYPO3 7.6.25
Powermail 4.4.0

Comment: I have got the same problem with TYPO3 8.7.12.
The only solution I found so far is to write an own Skript in an separate php-file and execute that file directly in the browser.
I do not understand why Powermail has got this performance issue. In our case there are 15'000 Mails.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact table structure, but maybe adding a useful index can boost up the queries.